# Is this formula correct? ${\rm rank}\ \mathcal A= {\rm rank}\ \mathcal B+\dim(\operatorname {Im}\mathcal A\cap \operatorname {ker} \mathcal B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I met an exercise that asks me to proof this formula. However, I propose there's something missing. Maybe adding some restrictions like ${\rm rank}\ \mathcal{A}\geq {\rm rank}\ \mathcal{B}$, where $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are linear operators on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$.

$$\operatorname {rank}\mathcal A=\operatorname {rank}\mathcal B+\dim(\operatorname {Im}\mathcal A\cap \operatorname {ker} \mathcal B)$$

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: By the question they are both taking $\;A,B\;$ as matrices (the rank thing) and as linear maps (the image thing)...but rank $\,A\;$ and $\;\dim\text{Im}\,A\;$ are exactly the same. And the formula is clearly wrong for the reason you mention: if $\;rank\,A<rank\,B\;$ then there is no way that equality can be true as all numbers in it are non-negative...

Comment: The exercise probably has a line before connecting $A$ and $B$. Without it, it is false.

Comment: If you replace $\operatorname{rank} \mathcal{B}$ with $\operatorname{rank} (\mathcal {BA})$ you get a correct formula by rank-nullity applied to $\mathcal{B} | \operatorname{Im} \mathcal{A}$.

Comment: thanks everyone!!!